# How to refresh the plot by actionbutton in different conitions in shinyapp

Tags: r, shiny, uioutput

I created a shinyapp and there are three vital buttons.

The three buttons works well

And the click3 can output a plot and a table togather.

Now in my app **they just refresh each other but only the table still stay  each time.**

**My question is now I want to modify some parts, I hope:**

**plot1 and plot2 will not refresh click3(plot3 and table) and click3 will not refresh plot1 or plot2.**

######### EDIT:2021-04-22 21:09:43

Sorry about that I didn't clarify my question.

Now `p1(),p2(), myPlot` can refresh each other.

But I hope `myPlot` and `myTable` can keep stay until new `click3` refresh themself. `p1() and p2()` can refresh each other but will not affect `myPlot` and `myTable`
So that `p1() or p2()` could stay togather with `myPlot` and `myTable` in mainparnel.

My reproducible code and data here:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
##  load("04.21_3.RData")

mean_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(sample(1:1000, 1000, replace = T), nrow = 20)
)
names(mean_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))

sd_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(runif(1000, 5, 10), nrow = 20)
)
names(sd_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))


############
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectizeInput(
      "selectGeneSymbol", 
      "Select:", 
      choices = NULL,
      multiple =F,
      width = 400,
      selected = NULL,
      options = list(placeholder = 'e.g. gene here',create = F)
    ),
    actionButton("plot1", "click1"),
    actionButton("plot2", "click2"),
    actionButton("dataTable", "click3")
  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("all"),
#    plotOutput("myPlot"),
    tableOutput("myTable")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  updateSelectizeInput(session, "selectGeneSymbol", choices = colnames(mean_data[,-1]), server = TRUE)
  
  global <- reactiveValues(out = NULL,
                           p1 = NULL,
                           p2 = NULL)
  plotdata <- eventReactive(input$plot1,{ 
    df <- mean_data %>% mutate(sd = sd_data[,input$selectGeneSymbol])
  })

  output$all <- renderUI({                      ##
    global$out
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plot1, {
    global$out <- plotOutput("plot1")

  })
  ##
  observeEvent(input$plot2, {
    global$out <- plotOutput("plot2")
    myData(NULL)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$dataTable, {
    global$out <- plotOutput("myPlot")
    myData(NULL)
  })
  ####
  myPlot = reactiveVal()
  myData = reactiveVal()
  
  observeEvent(input$dataTable, {
    data_cor<-mean_data[,-1]
    tm <- corr.test(data_cor[,input$selectGeneSymbol,drop=FALSE],
                    y = data_cor, use = "pairwise", "spearman", adjust="none", 
                    alpha=0.05, ci=F, minlength=5)
    res <-setNames(as.data.frame(t(do.call(rbind, tm[c("r", "p")]))), c("Correlation", "P_value"))
    res<-res[-which(rownames(res)== input$selectGeneSymbol),]
    res<-data.frame(Gene=rownames(res),res)
    res
    ##############
    data_correlation=t(mean_data[, -1])
    data_subset=data_correlation[c(input$selectGeneSymbol, as.vector(head(res$Gene, 10))), ]
    myPlot(
        pheatmap(log2(data_subset+1), show_colnames = F,fontsize_row =12,
                 cluster_rows = F, cluster_cols = F, gaps_row = 1)
    )
    myData(res)
  })
  
  output$myPlot = renderPlot({
    myPlot()
  })
  
  output$myTable = renderTable({
    myData()
  })
  
  ####
  p1 <- eventReactive(input$plot1,
                      {
                        ggplot(data =plotdata(), aes(x = Name, y = .data[[as.name(input$selectGeneSymbol)]])) +
                          geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
                          theme(legend.position = "none") +
                          labs(title = paste(input$selectGeneSymbol), x = NULL, y = "666666")                      })
  
  p2 <- eventReactive(input$plot2,
                      {
                        ggplot(data = plotdata(), aes(x = Name, y = .data[[as.name(input$selectGeneSymbol)]], fill=Name)) +
                          geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
                          theme(legend.position = "none") +
                          labs(title = paste(input$selectGeneSymbol), x = NULL, y = "777777")                      })                    
                      
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    p1()})
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    p2()})
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @YBS Sir, could you give me some advice.

Comment: Your message does not show show up for me.  Perhaps you need a comma `,` after @YBS.  I am not sure that I understand your question here. It should work the way you expect in this case.  Please note that I have answered your other question a few minutes ago - and it looks like the same code is given there also.  As you did not include `corr.test()` function this is not an MRE.  In the future, please include the functions you use or use publicly available dataset and plot them, such as, `plot(cars)`, `plot(pressure)` or use your other plots `p1()` or `p2()`

Comment: @YBS, thanks,sir. I get it.

Comment: @YBS, I mean if I can modify my code so that the plot1 and plot2 can refresh each other but they will not affect the dataTable output(myPlot and myData). And when dataTable output(myPlot and myData) only click3 could refresh it ?  When click1 or click2 run, the dataTable output(myPlot and myData) still stay in mainpanel

Comment: Please note that I am still not clear on your needs.  Perhaps you need to clarify your needs in the question above or ask a new question.  Too much information in the comments is not a good idea.  As the object `global$out` is either `plot1`, `plot2` or `myPlot`, you can only display one object.  You can display myTable - continuously or only when you click on `click3`.  Please clarify what you want to display in the main panel when you click on each actionButton.  Ideally, such clarification should be shown in the question and not in comments.

Comment: @YBS, sorry,sir. Please view my new edit.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is your expectation

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
##  load("04.21_3.RData")

mean_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(sample(1:1000, 1000, replace = T), nrow = 20)
)
names(mean_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))

sd_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(runif(1000, 5, 10), nrow = 20)
)
names(sd_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))


############
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectizeInput(
      "selectGeneSymbol", 
      "Select:", 
      choices = NULL,
      multiple =F,
      width = 400,
      selected = NULL,
      options = list(placeholder = 'e.g. gene here',create = F)
    ),
    actionButton("plot1", "click1"),
    actionButton("plot2", "click2"),
    actionButton("dataTable", "click3")
  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("all"),
    plotOutput("myPlot"),
    tableOutput("myTable")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  updateSelectizeInput(session, "selectGeneSymbol", choices = colnames(mean_data[,-1]), server = TRUE)
  
  global <- reactiveValues(out = NULL,
                           p1 = NULL,
                           p2 = NULL)
  plotdata <- eventReactive(input$plot1,{ 
    df <- mean_data %>% mutate(sd = sd_data[,input$selectGeneSymbol])
  })
  
  output$all <- renderUI({                      ##
    global$out
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plot1, {
    global$out <- plotOutput("plot1")
    #myData(NULL)
  })
  ##
  observeEvent(input$plot2, {
    global$out <- plotOutput("plot2")
    #myData(NULL)
  })
  
  # observeEvent(input$dataTable, {
  #   global$out <- plotOutput("myPlot")
  #   
  # })
  ####
  myPlot = reactiveVal()
  myData = reactiveVal()
  
  observeEvent(input$dataTable, {
    # data_cor<-mean_data[,-1]
    # tm <- corr.test(data_cor[,input$selectGeneSymbol,drop=FALSE],
    #                 y = data_cor, use = "pairwise", "spearman", adjust="none", 
    #                 alpha=0.05, ci=F, minlength=5)
    # res <-setNames(as.data.frame(t(do.call(rbind, tm[c("r", "p")]))), c("Correlation", "P_value"))
    # res<-res[-which(rownames(res)== input$selectGeneSymbol),]
    # res<-data.frame(Gene=rownames(res),res)
    # res
    # ##############
    # data_correlation=t(mean_data[, -1])
    # data_subset=data_correlation[c(input$selectGeneSymbol, as.vector(head(res$Gene, 10))), ]
    # myPlot(
    #   pheatmap(log2(data_subset+1), show_colnames = F,fontsize_row =12,
    #            cluster_rows = F, cluster_cols = F, gaps_row = 1)
    # )
    # myData(res)
    
    myData(mtcars)
  })
  
  p3 <- eventReactive(input$dataTable, {
    hist(runif(500))
  })
  
  output$myPlot = renderPlot({
    p3()
    #myPlot()
  })
  
  output$myTable = renderTable({
    myData()
  })
  
  ####
  p1 <- eventReactive(input$plot1,
                      {
                        ggplot(data =plotdata(), aes(x = Name, y = .data[[as.name(input$selectGeneSymbol)]])) +
                          geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
                          theme(legend.position = "none") +
                          labs(title = paste(input$selectGeneSymbol), x = NULL, y = "666666")                      })
  
  p2 <- eventReactive(input$plot2,
                      {
                        ggplot(data = plotdata(), aes(x = Name, y = .data[[as.name(input$selectGeneSymbol)]], fill=Name)) +
                          geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
                          theme(legend.position = "none") +
                          labs(title = paste(input$selectGeneSymbol), x = NULL, y = "777777")                      })                    
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    p1()})
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    p2()})
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```